# EF Core 2.0 and raw queries

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am pretty sure I have done something like this in EF Core 2:

```
// Not in Db
public class MyCustomProjection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DbSet<MyCustomProjection> dummy { get; set; }

    public List<MyCustomProjection> GetCustomProjectedBlogs()
    {
        return dummy.FromSql("SELECT Id, Title AS Name FROM Blogs").ToListAsync();   
    }
}
```

In order to be able to query FromSql into custom projection I added a DbSet with my projection entity to my DbContext and added annotation [NotMapped].

I am certain this used to work but now it seems If I use NotMapped annotation it will create the table anyways and if I use Fluent api Ignore with the entity, the table won't be created but EF will produce an error saying you cannot project into an ignored entity.

I no longer have access to my old code (in another company) and I cannot recreate this bit. 
Someone please explain if my memory is broken or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have done something similar. I don't need the [NotMapped] and I have a .ToListAsync(); at the end of the select.

Comment: Have you tried dummy.FromSql<MyCustomProjection>("...") ?

Comment: I added the [NotMapped] to try and prevent MyCustomProjection from being created as a table on add-migration. But it seems that EF Core ignores that annotation and creates the table anyway.
And, yes I used ToListAsync() as well (forgot to put it in example) and the code works - but only if the table MyCustomProjection is there - and the whole idea with a custom projection is that it is not represented by any table in the db.

Comment: @tom do your EF create the custom projection entity as table in db?

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen I do the same as you - my context has a DbSet<MyReturnedColumns>

Comment: @tom Ok, so do you end up with a MyReturnedRows table in your sql database? (that was what i really wanted to know)

Comment: @H.Herzl the type is implied by the DbSet<MYCustomProjection> - and my code is working, only it creates a MyCustomProjection table in the sql db which was not my intention.

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen are you saying that you want a new table in the db?

Comment: This way has never worked in past. Whenever you add a DbSet property, a corresponding entityType will be added to the model which will create a database model. NotMapped attribute on DbSet has no effect as far as I can see in history of EFCore.

Comment: The feature you need is https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862 It allows you to use FromSql on a type which is not part of model for creating a table.

Comment: @tom will your answer depend on my answer?

Comment: @Smit thanx - I see it will be available in version 2.1 and since I'm not going to upgrade my VS2017 to preview just for that, it's going to have to wait.
( - I may not remember what I did in .Net core 1.x but I know for sure when we switched from old .Net framework to Core 1.x that we could no longer use raw queries with custom projection poco's. But after I found the solution I was referring to I definetly did not have a table named after each of my projection poco)